# How to populate the firebaseConfig in a Node.js file?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to make a **Vehicle** or **Transport**  **Tracker** application project using google map and android device. For this reason I am using Firebase for online database hosting, a custom hosting as server and an android application installed on device.

I am following [this Tutorial / Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/transport-tracker/start)

However I have created

1. A new Firebase project
2. Created the Google Map API key
3. Uploaded all the files into [web server](http://tarunnodev.com/) from the [map](https://github.com/googlemaps/transport-tracker/tree/master/map) folder, the main GitHub project is [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/transport-tracker)

But in [this Tutorial / Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/transport-tracker/start) the **Step 5** is confusing to me or I don't know what to do.

In the **Step 5** the **4th no.** instruction says that : Edit the **js/index.js** file and populate the **firebaseConfig** object with the Firebase authentication values.

Well, I have the index.js file under js folder but, how can I populate the firebaseConfig object with the Firebase authentication values to the index.js file in the server?

The index.js is [in this link](http://tarunnodev.com/js/index.js)

Comment: I'll let the documentation team know that the tutorial isn't clear, but in the mean time here are the codelabs I built for walking people through the construction of this solution: [Transport Tracker Backend](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/transport-tracker-backend/), [Transport Tracker Map](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/transport-tracker-map/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So step 5 is referring to the the service account JSON file you obtain from the Firebase console. The service account JSON file contains sensitive information such as an RSA private key. Because of the sensitive data within the file, as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app):

> **Important:** This file contains sensitive information, including your service account's private encryption key. Keep it confidential and never store it in a public repository.

With that said, the tutorial you're following doesn't explain what the `firebaseConfig` object should look like. However, if you examine the source of the `index.js`, it explicitly tells you what to do:

```
// TODO: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup for how to configure access to Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {};
```

Visiting that URL linked above yields the following:

```
const config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
}
```

That above is what your `firebaseConfig` object should look like. However, what's confusing me is why the tutorial is asking you to create a service account to begin with as you don't appear to be needing admin access from a privileged environment such as a server. On top of that, the JSON service account file it asks you download does not even contain the values needed for the `firebaseConfig` object.

With that said, follow the directions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) to add firebase to your web project. Modify `firebaseConfig` in the `index.js` to use the credentials you obtain from above. You should be looking at a modal like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzE3l.jpg) to obtain the correct config.